# AWS Cloudfront modifies Strapi headers

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-ecs, strapi, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm running Strapi on an ECS cluster sitting behind an ALB. I put a Cloudfront distribution in front of the load balancer, but it breaks the app just after login. For routes /content-manager/content-types, /admin/information and /i18n/locales, I get a 404 response when going through Cloudfront.

What I noticed, is that when using Cloudfront the responses for these calls have "content-type: text/plain" in them, and I've no idea where it's coming from. Note that this happens for these specific calls, and the requests did not change.

Here's the response for example.com/content-types WITHOUT Cloudfront:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
date: Wed, 04 Aug 2021 04:59:52 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-length: 25870
vary: Origin
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: Strapi <strapi.io>
x-response-time: 42ms
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Here's the response for example.com/content-types WITH Cloudfront:

```
HTTP/2 404 Not Found
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-length: 9
date: Wed, 04 Aug 2021 04:55:46 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: Strapi <strapi.io>
x-response-time: 2ms
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 <masked>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: <masked>
x-amz-cf-id: <masked>
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

I have managed to work around it, by creating a behaviour that allows all headers, but that feels like shooting a cannon at sparrows - does anyone know why does Strapi respond differently/why doesn't Cloudfront forward headers for specific calls?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your application requires certain request values in order to return the correct response. When you placed CloudFront in front of your app, some of those values did not make it to your origin and your application returned a different response (404 rather than 200).

By default, CloudFront does not send all headers/request values to your origin. You'll need to identify what request values your application needs, and then ensure those specific headers/query strings/cookie values are sent to your origin by CloudFront. You can use a **cache policy** if the values should be included in the cache key, or an **origin request policy** if you want to send values to your origin but not include them in the cache key.

Comment: Here's the announcement for more details: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-cloudfront-announces-cache-and-origin-request-policies/